# If the city name Napoli comes from Ancient Greek "Nea Polis" (new town), why isn't it called "Gnapoli" instead?

Tags: ancient-greek, italian

If the city name Napoli comes from Ancient Greek "Nea Polis" (new town), why isn't it called "Gnapoli" instead? Why wasn't the 'n' at the beginning yotated by the following 'e'?

Comment: The *e* in *Neāpolis* is short.